# Update second window UI from the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I declared a private variable on the `MainWindow` class so i would be able to use it later:

```
private GraphicPresenterWindow _GraphicPresenterWindow;
```

On the `MainWindow` constructor i have the following line opening a new window:

```
_GraphicPresenterWindow = new GraphicPresenterWindow();
_GraphicPresenterWindow.Show();
```

Both windows remain open at the same time.

My problem is when I'm trying to update the `Visibility` for some `StackPanels` and the `Text` for the `TextBlocks` from my main window.

Here is the code (for brevity i didn't post the entire method):

```
private void MainWindow_ShowFirstGraphBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // previous code omitted

    var CanShow = PresenterAPI.CanShowFirstGraph();
    if (CanShow)
    {
        _GraphicPresenterWindow.InitialGraphStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _GraphicPresenterWindow.FirstGraphStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        _GraphicPresenterWindow.FirstGraphTxtBlock.Text = string.Format("{0} retrospective", _YearNo);
    }

    // following code omitted
}
```

The second window updates but only when the entire `MainWindow_ShowFirstGraphBtn_Click` method is executed.

How can i force the second window to update the values as the calls in this method are made?

I also tried using a `Dispatcher` but no result.

Comment: you need to bind these UI controls to the same ViewModel properties simply by following MVVM pattern

Comment: I kinda tried what you're saying but didn't worked (i guess there is some mistake i made). I ended using different threads for the windows and updating UI with the dispatcher. However i would preferred to use a single thread method.

Comment: you should post the code you've tried with relevant issues. the code you've already posted is not relevant to this approach. by the way, binding is not related to multithreading, you can use 1 or many threads. property changes callbacks are automatically marshalled back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Even when using data binding and view-models as suggested in the comments to your question, you will observe the same issue with a single-threaded approach.

The reason for it is the fact that you want to execute the "hard work" (your `MainWindow_ShowFirstGraphBtn_Click` method) on the main thread. While your method is executing, the WPF `Dispatcher` is unable to do its job, it just waits for your method to finish. The `Dispatcher` is responsible for queuing of so-called dispatcher operations, which include e.g. data-binding, rendering, or input processing.

When you execute this code in your method:

```
InitialGraphStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

you effectively just state an *intent* to change the element's visibility. In order this to actually happen, the WPF `Dispatcher` needs to queue *and execute* a couple of operations: dependency property update and render. But this is impossible while your method continues. This is the explanation why you only see the changes when your method returns, or in a multi-threaded solution (there, the `Dispatcher` can queue operations independently of your method which runs on a worker thread).

You have two options now:

- A multi-threaded solution (run your "hard work" method on a worker thread).
- Chunk your method into pieces and let the `Dispatcher` kick-in several times while your long-running processing is executing. There is [an example in the WPF Threading Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model) documentation how to do that.